# Can I do a merge restore from Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore, macos

A few months ago for some reason that is not important, a large number of my files were mistakenly deleted. I did not notice for several weeks, so the later backups are of the remaining files only. I don't know how to reconstruct the file system. If I restore from an old backup, I lose all my later work. If I restore from a recent backup I lose the files that were deleted. There are hundreds or thousands of files involved so I can't do them individually.

I think I need some kind of merge restore, so I tried a `cp -npRx` from the Time Machine disk to the SSD, but that seems to have caused problems with access control lists.

Is there some way I could, perhaps, delete an entire directory tree, restore from an old backup and then merge in any newer files from all the more recent backups?

Comment: Why not just restore only the missing files? Use Time Machine itself, don't try to do it from Terminal. Time Machine is designed to be a GUI app, not a dive into Terminal.

Comment: There are hundreds or thousands of missing files. I can't do that by hand.

Comment: what @Tetsujin said, first restore from the older back up, then restore from newer back up, it will not delete the restored files

Comment: OK, I'll try that.

Comment: While Time Machine is designed for the GUI, it's generally perfectly safe to copy out of Finder/Terminal. That being said, if your missing files are concentrated in one area, is that area small enough you can restore a copy then merge the two folder hierarchies?

Comment: A downside with `cp` is it won't remove Time Machine metadata. See `man tmutil` for `restore` verb which removes that (like "extended security and other"). Is that the issue you're having? `tmutil restore` doesn't support `cp` flags like `-n` though. So, perhaps first restore to empty location with `tmutil restore`, then `cp -npRx` from there to final destination. As a side note, in case interested, I'm working on a Time Machine helper app & have opened a [support merge options](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/time-machine-helper/issues/4) issue like you're wanting.

Comment: OK, thanks all. I think I have enough info to make progress now.